# Deployment of translations of custom labels using ANT

Tags: ant, customlabel, translation

We have a very large number of translations for custom labels. could any one guide me in how to create package.xml for deploying translations into new sandbox using Ant.

I retrieved translation data , but while deployment please guide me the syntax of package.xml.

Below is the package.xml, I have created for retrieving.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
      <members>*</members>
      <name>CustomLabels</name>
    </types>
   <types>
      <members>*</members>
      <name>Translations</name>
   </types>
  <version>36.0</version>
  </Package>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it happens:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
      <types>
         <members>en_US</members>
         <name>Translations</name>
      </types>
     <version>36.0</version>
  </Package>
```

Label translations have name of the language. You would be getting it like en_US.translation.